# Send data from VC to cell without transition

Tags: ios, swift

I’ m writing a days tracker app. Everything is set up in code. There is a TabBarController with embedded ViewController(VC) and TableViewController(TVC).
In VC i count days passed from the moment the button was pressed to the end date with an interval. When the goal is reached I save these three variables in UserDefaults (startDate, endDate, numberOfDays). 
And then I want these parameters be sent to the TVC to save them in a cell without transition between controllers.
I’ve got a separated model for cell:

```
class Info {
    var start: String?
    var end: String?
    var total: String?
}

class InfoCell: UITableViewCell {

    let padding: CGFloat = 10.0
    let startInfoLabel = UILabel.makeLabel(text: "", size: 15, textColor: .black)
    let endInfoLabel = UILabel.makeLabel(text: "", size: 15, textColor: .black)
    let totalInfoLabel = UILabel.makeLabel(text: "", size: 20, textColor: .red)

    var info: Info? {
        didSet {
            guard let infoItem = info else { return }
            if let start = infoItem.start {
                startInfoLabel.text = start 
                print(start)
            }
            if let end = infoItem.end {
                endInfoLabel.text = end
            }
            if let total = infoItem.total {
                totalInfoLabel.text = total
            }
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.contentView.addSubview(startInfoLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(endInfoLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(totalInfoLabel)

        totalInfoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        startInfoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        totalInfoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        startInfoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.totalInfoLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        endInfoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.startInfoLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
        endInfoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
   }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }}

class HistoryViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellId = "CellId"
    var infos = [Info]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(InfoCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return infos.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! InfoCell
        let currentLastItem = infos[indexPath.row]
        cell.info = currentLastItem
        return cell
    }
}
```

And in VC I send data through function:

```
func stopSuccessfully() {
        timer?.invalidate()

        startTime = defaults.value(forKey: "StartTimer")
        endTime = defaults.value(forKey: "EndTimer")
        totalNumber = defaults.integer(forKey: "TotalNumber")

        var newCell = Info()
        newCell.start = startTime?.toString()
        newCell.end = endTime?.toString()
        newCell.total = "\(totalNumer)"
    }
```

That’s my first app and I can't come to any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a delegate design pattern.

```
protocol MyviewControllerDelegate {
    func addInfo(_ info: Info)
}

class MyViewControler {
    var delegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?

    private func stopSuccessfully() {
        // your code...
        if let myDelegate = delegate {
            myDelegate.addInfo(newCell)
        } else { print("delegate error") }
    }
}

class MyTableViewController {

    private var myVC: MyViewController!

    overide viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // create an instance of MyViewController
        myVC = storyboard.instanceWithIndentifier(identifier: 
    "myViewController") as? MyViewController
        myVC.delegate = self
    }
}

extention MyTableViewController: MyViewControllerDelegate {
    //use stub
    func addInfo(_ info: Info) {
        // append info to infos array
        infos.append(info)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot! the only thing I added: instead of instantiation myVC in TVC,  I wrote VC.delegate = TVC in TabBarVC so that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Once an app gets to the point where data needs to be shared among multiple view or controller classes, it's time for that data model to be separate from the display layer.  Communication between two controllers may not be too bad but few apps stop at two.  :)

Here's a very simple model.  (Note: some people hate Singletons and there are ways to avoid them but I'm using one here for the sake of simplicity.)

```
class InfoManager {
    private var infos = [Info]()
    static let instance = InfoManager()
    static let dataModelChanged = Notification.Name("dataModelChanged")

    func infoCount() -> Int {
        return infos.count
    }

    func infoElement(at offset: Int) -> Info {
        return infos[offset]
    }

    func addInfo(_ info: Info) {
        infos.append(info)

        // Other objects may need to know about changes
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: InfoManager.dataModelChanged, object: nil)
    }
}
```

To react to the addition of new data, your TVC would then react to a notification.

```
class InfoUser {
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dataChanged(_:)), name: InfoManager.dataModelChanged, object: nil)
    }
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func dataChanged(_ notification:Notification) {
        print("Here's where I reload my table")
    }
}
```

Put the above code into a playground along with your `Info` definition and you can see its operation with....

```
let user = InfoUser()
let element = Info()
element.start = "Start"
element.end = "End"
element.total = "Total"
InfoManager.instance.addInfo(element)
let last = InfoManager.instance.infoCount() - 1
print(InfoManager.instance.infoElement(at: last).start)
```

Comment: Too complicated for me at my stage of learning) but i'll try to figure it out

Comment: That's fair but, if there's something I can explain about it, feel free to ask.